# Scraping dynamic information of stock data using Python

Tags: python, html, dynamic, web

I am trying to use Python to scrap dynamic stock information from a Chinese website :

**http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#cyb_root**

However, I am a newer to Python. So can someone give me a hand for this? Thanks so much.

All I wanna do is scraping the HTML dynamic data from the above website.

Comment: Open your Firebug/Chrome's Developer tools, go to the Network tab, and reload the page. It's sending AJAX requests to a JSON api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ or http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/.

If you want to follow lots of links or you need to crawl differents types on objects. I highly recommand scrapy. If you need an exemple for your website let me know, both libraries are very simple to use.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have no idea about how to do that. Can someone give me the code for this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your website and in your case it's simpler to do the crawler with a browser automation tool like selenium, here is working example for sina.com.cn:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#cyb_root")
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='tbl_wrap']//tbody/tr")
for row in rows:
    name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./th[@class='sort_down']/a").text
    values = [v.text for v in row.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[@class='colorize']")]
    print "%s : %s" % (name, values)
driver.close()
```

if you run this script, you'll get:

```
$ python sina_com.py
sz300001 : [u'16.51', u'+0.64', u'+4.033%', u'16.51', u'16.52', u'15.87', u'15.86', u'16.58', u'15.80']
sz300002 : [u'--', u'0.00', u'0.000%', u'0.00', u'0.00', u'19.34', u'0.00', u'0.00', u'0.00']
sz300003 : [u'10.86', u'-0.05', u'-0.458%', u'10.85', u'10.86', u'10.91', u'10.98', u'10.98', u'10.59']
sz300004 : [u'22.86', u'+1.21', u'+5.589%', u'22.86', u'22.87', u'21.65', u'21.74', u'22.98', u'21.10']
sz300005 : [u'10.91', u'+0.35', u'+3.314%', u'10.91', u'10.94', u'10.56', u'10.51', u'10.99', u'10.51']
.....
```

:) good luck

Comment: Thank u so much!!!  But how can I get rid of all these quotes and the "u" strings?

Comment: u"" means only that the array contains unicode strings, you can convert them to floats by doing:
values = [float(v.text) for v in row.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[@class='colorize']")]

don't forget that you have to add some exception for values like u"--"